# Zend_Gdata: Retrieving text document content?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-gdata

Retrieving spreadsheet content using for a specific spreadsheet isn't that hard:

```
$key = 'txSLYk4BpIQaglM38cJbTNA'; // key for a specific spreadsheet
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($key);
$feed = $spreadSheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
$entries = $feed->entries[0]->getContentsAsRows();
var_dump($entries); // dumps the spreadsheet content
```

Can I do the same for a specific text document?
The Zend_Gdata_Docs_Query class doesn't have a ->setDocumentKey($key) or equivalent...

/ Jonas

Answer (score -1):

(note: I haven't worked with ZF's GData API myself... this is speculative, based on browsing through the API)

It looks like you can call `Zend_Gdata_Docs::getDoc()` - this will return a `Zend_Gdata_Docs_DocumentListEntry` which in turn exposes a `getContent()` method.

So:

```
$docsApi  = new  Zend_Gdata_Docs();
$document = $docsApi->getDoc('key-goes-here', 'document');
$content  = $document->getContent(); // Returns the ATOM content
// OR...
$content  = $document->getDOM(); // Returns a DOM for the content
```

It looks like the spreadsheet is a more specialised form of this more generic way of retrieving Google Docs content.

Comment: Hmm.. It looks like it's only possible to get document metadata using these methods, not the document content itself.